# Springboot GET API to show response from multiple collections after combing them based on Id

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm working on a Springboot application with mongoDB. I'm creating a GET API, which returns data from DB. My requirement is I want to return the response after combining data from multiple collections, without actually changing the DB data or schema.

For ex:

**MainCollection:**

```
{
_id: 123, name: abc, value: 132,
subCollectionDetails: {
   subCollectionId : 1111-1111,
   subCollectionOtherValues: "Some data", 
  }
},
{
_id: 124, name: fff, value: 132,
subCollectionDetails: {
   subCollectionId : 1111-2222,
   subCollectionOtherValues: "Some data", 
  }
}.
{
_id: 125, name: abc, value: 132,
subCollectionDetails: {
   subCollectionId : 1111-3333,
   subCollectionOtherValues: "Some data", 
  }
}
```

**SubCollectionId :**

```
{
_id: 1111-1111, 
subCollectionName : "sub1",
subCollectionPresent : True 
}
{
_id: 1111-2222, 
subCollectionName : "sub1",
subCollectionPresent : True 
}
```

Final GET API response Response :

```
{
_id: 123, name: abc, value: 132,
subCollectionDetails: {
   _id: 1111-1111, 
   subCollectionName : "sub1",
   subCollectionPresent : True 
   subCollectionOtherValues: "Some data", 
  }
},
{
_id: 124, name: fff, value: 132,
subCollectionDetails: {
   _id: 1111-2222, 
   subCollectionName : "sub1",
   subCollectionPresent : True 
   subCollectionOtherValues: "Some data", 
  }
}.
{
_id: 125, name: abc, value: 132,
subCollectionDetails: {
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem ?

Comment: I want to send the expected response which I have added.

Comment: I think you can achive that in two different ways: first - do that in Java or second - use mongoDB lookup https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: Can you help me with that. I  want to achieve this without changing the data or schema in the DB. Does aggregate function actually change the data in the DB?

Comment: No, aggregate functions don't change data in collections. If you want exactly same response from mongodb, after lookup you can use project method.

Comment: Can you give a small example for the same @MateuszJaszewski

Comment: Yes, I've posted an answer. Check if that meets your needs ;)

Answer (score 0):

That query should return what you want:

```
db.main.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "sub",
      localField: "subCollectionDetails.subCollectionId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "sub_lookup"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: true,
      name: true,
      value: true,
      subCollectionDetails: {
        $mergeObjects: [
            "$subCollectionDetails",
            {$arrayElemAt: ["$sub_lookup",0]}
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "subCollectionDetails.subCollectionId": false
    }
  }
])
```

You can run this here https://mongoplayground.net/p/k-vkqoaH8nd

Comment: Second $project just remove subCollectionDetails.subCollectionId field from response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DTO projection as interface or class. which fields are required that filed are taken into interface projection with getter method or in DTO class you can also define which fields you want.